# Which swift screen handler approach is better for instantiating a utility class and then presenting a viewController?

Tags: functional-programming, comparative-review, swift, ios

**1<sup>st</sup> approach:**

```
let whatsNewHandler = WhatsNewHandler(buildNumber: buildNumber)
 whatsNewHandler.showWhatNewScreeen(completion: { whatsNewVC in

      self.present(whatsNewVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
 })
```

**2<sup>nd</sup> approach, which looks a bit functional:**

```
WhatsNewHandler(buildNumber: buildNumber).showWhatNewScreeen(completion: { whatsNewVC in

      self.present(whatsNewVC, animated: true, completion: nil)               
})
```

While both allocate the same amount of memory. I like the functional approach, I just do something and that's really it. But the reason I'm asking is I haven't seen anyone write like this. I see things similar to it when you're using a singleton, but this isn't a singleton.

**EDIT:**

My WhatNewHandler class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit



typealias WhatsNewCompletionHandler = (_ whatsNewViewController: WhatsNewViewController) -> ()

class WhatsNewHandler{

    let buildNumber : String
    lazy var route : Router = {
      return Router.whatsNew(buildNumber: self.buildNumber)
    }()

    init(buildNumber: String){
        self.buildNumber = buildNumber
    }

    func showWhatNewScreeen(completion: @escaping WhatsNewCompletionHandler){

        NetworkHandler.sharedInstance.request(route, success: { json,_  in

            guard let json = json else{
                writelog("what's new json was nil")
                return
            }
            if let releaseBuild = ReleaseBuild(json: json){
                let WhatsNewVC = WhatsNewViewController(releaseBuild: releaseBuild)
                WhatsNewVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen

                // TEST ALPHA ON REAL DEVICE
                WhatsNewVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.985)
                completion(WhatsNewVC)
            }
            }, failed: {_,_,_ in

        })
    }
}
```

As for my WhatsNewViewController, kindly assume it to be a Viewcontroller that shows a list of new features added to the app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67788/discussion-between-honey-and-martin-r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between the first and the second approach is whether 
the handler is assigned to a variable or not. None of them is more 
"functional" than the other. Therefore:

- If you need a reference to the handler (perhaps to cancel the request)
  then use the first approach.
- If you don't need that reference, choose whatever you feel more
  comfortable with, or what you find better readable.

Some more remarks:

- The method name `showWhatNewScreeen` is (apart from the typo)
  misleading. The method *creates* a view controller but does not
  present it. Something like `createWhatsNewController` might be 
  more appropriate.
- According to the [API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/), variable names should be `lowerCamelCase`, that is violated at
  `let WhatsNewVC = ...`.
- The right-hand side of

  ```
  whatsNewVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.985)
  ```

  can be abbreviated to `.black.withAlphaComponent(0.985)`, the
  type `UIColor` is then inferred from the context.